# use array to add and name new sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to create a given number of sheets, depending on the amount of names in a List. The sheets need to have the same name as the string value in every cell inside the list/array. So far my code, which is not working:

```
Private Sub loopfilter()

Dim VersandRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Name As String

Set VersandRange = Range("J2", Cells(Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp))

    For Each rng In VersandRange

            rng.Value = Name
            Worksheets.Add
            ActiveSheet.Name = Name
    Next
end sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: One line is reversed     **Name=rng.Value**

Comment: or just `Worksheets.Add.Name = rng.Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this not work?

```
For Each rng In VersandRange
    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = rng.Value
Next
```

Comment: @Urumita sheet names are limited to 31 characters and can't contain any of those 7 characters `\/*[]:?` http://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/seven-characters-you-cant-use-in-worksheet-names

Comment: Thank you slai, but it is not the case. Im using none of those characters and the maximum =Long I have is 22

Comment: You've only swapped out the `For.. Next` part of your code with mine, yes?

Comment: What is the rest of the error generated under code 1004?